# How do i find image properties to process that image automatically?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am new at image processing. I want to develop an OCR. For that, i have to process images. I am using opencv-contrib-python3.4.0 library for image processing.  There will be different types of image from different camera. If i put some static value for image processing it works for one or two image not for every image i get. so, is there any suitable Algorithm which i can find out image properties and find threshold value or brightness value automatically to process all image?

Comment: No one method is suitable for thresholding every possible image. Otsu thresholding works well for some images. Adaptive thresholding works in other situations. It all depends upon the image content.

Comment: Take a look at [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) and [adaptive threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#adaptive-thresholding)

Comment: I tried Otsu's threshold and adaptive threshold but result was same. It shows perfect result for some images and some do not.